# Deluge have no init scripts?

Tags: init.d, deluge

Deluge have no init scripts in raspberry pi repository?

```
root@rpi ~# service deluged start
deluged: unrecognized service
root@rpi ~# service deluge-web
deluge-web: unrecognized service
```

But deluged and deluge-web are installed :(,

Comment: deluged is a very heavy program.  Have you tried using *rtorrent*.  There are GU interfaces for it.

Answer (score 3):

## deluged init script

#### Instructions

- `sudo wget https://gist.github.com/earthmeLon/a4bf68d385f8f840d2b5/raw/ -O /etc/init.d/deluged`

  - This downloads the script and places it in the correct directory
- `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/deluged`

  - This allows execution of the new file, which is essential for it to be run at startup
- `sudo update-rc.d deluged defaults`

  - This loads the default init settings for deluged
- `sudo update-rc.d deluged enable`

  - This turns on the loaded settings for deluged so that it will be loaded at boot

#### [CLI/Old Script](https://gist.github.com/earthmeLon/a4bf68d385f8f840d2b5)

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          deluged
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $network
# Should-Stop:       $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start or stop the Deluge BitTorrent daemon.
# Description:       Start or stop the Deluge BitTorrent daemon.
### END INIT INFO

# Authors: Tanguy Ortolo <tanguy+debian@ortolo.eu>,
# Cristian Greco <cristian@regolo.cc>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Deluge BitTorrent Daemon"
NAME="deluged"
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-d -c /var/lib/deluged/config -l /var/log/deluged/daemon.log -L info"
USER=debian-deluged
MASK=0027
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

ENABLE_DELUGED=1

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
  if [ $ENABLE_DELUGED != 1 ]; then
    log_progress_msg "Not starting ${DESC} ${NAME}, disabled in /etc/default/${NAME}"
  else
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON \
      --chuid $USER --umask $MASK --test > /dev/null \
      || return 1

    start-stop-daemon --start --background --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON \
      --chuid $USER --umask $MASK -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
      || return 2
  fi
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
  # Return
  #   0 if daemon has been stopped
  #   1 if daemon was already stopped
  #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
  #   other if a failure occurred

  start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE
  RETVAL="$?"
  [ "$RETVAL" = "2" ] && return 2

  rm -f $PIDFILE
  return "$RETVAL"
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
          0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
          1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
          *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

#### Notes

It has been brought to my attention via comments of this answer that this init script *does not* work with deluge's webui.  Please look at the documentation at [deluge's website](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu) for further information.  The following is their script:

#### [WebUI/New Script](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu)

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          deluge-daemon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $network
# Should-Stop:       $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Daemonized version of deluge and webui.
# Description:       Starts the deluge daemon with the user specified in
#                    /etc/default/deluge-daemon.
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Adolfo R. Brandes 
# Updated by: Jean-Philippe "Orax" Roemer

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="Deluge Daemon"
NAME1="deluged"
NAME2="deluge"
DAEMON1=/usr/bin/deluged
DAEMON1_ARGS="-d"             # Consult `man deluged` for more options
DAEMON2=/usr/bin/deluge-web
DAEMON2_ARGS=""               # Consult `man deluge-web` for more options
PIDFILE1=/var/run/$NAME1.pid
PIDFILE2=/var/run/$NAME2.pid
UMASK=022                     # Change this to 0 if running deluged as its own user
PKGNAME=deluge-daemon
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$PKGNAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON1" -a -x "$DAEMON2" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$PKGNAME ] && . /etc/default/$PKGNAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -z "$RUN_AT_STARTUP" -o "$RUN_AT_STARTUP" != "YES" ]
then
   log_warning_msg "Not starting $PKGNAME, edit /etc/default/$PKGNAME to start it."
   exit 0
fi

if [ -z "$DELUGED_USER" ]
then
    log_warning_msg "Not starting $PKGNAME, DELUGED_USER not set in /etc/default/$PKGNAME."
    exit 0
fi

#
# Function to verify if a pid is alive
#
is_alive()
{
   pid=`cat $1` > /dev/null 2>&1
   kill -0 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
   return $?
}

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
   # Return
   #   0 if daemon has been started
   #   1 if daemon was already running
   #   2 if daemon could not be started

   is_alive $PIDFILE1
   RETVAL1="$?"

   if [ $RETVAL1 != 0 ]; then
       rm -f $PIDFILE1
       start-stop-daemon --start --background --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE1 --make-pidfile \
       --exec $DAEMON1 --chuid $DELUGED_USER --user $DELUGED_USER --umask $UMASK -- $DAEMON1_ARGS
       RETVAL1="$?"
   else
       is_alive $PIDFILE2
       RETVAL2="$?"
       [ "$RETVAL2" = "0" -a "$RETVAL1" = "0" ] && return 1
   fi

   is_alive $PIDFILE2
   RETVAL2="$?"

   if [ $RETVAL2 != 0 ]; then
        sleep 2
        rm -f $PIDFILE2
        start-stop-daemon --start --background --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE2 --make-pidfile \
        --exec $DAEMON2 --chuid $DELUGED_USER --user $DELUGED_USER --umask $UMASK -- $DAEMON2_ARGS
        RETVAL2="$?"
   fi
   [ "$RETVAL1" = "0" -a "$RETVAL2" = "0" ] || return 2
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
   # Return
   #   0 if daemon has been stopped
   #   1 if daemon was already stopped
   #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
   #   other if a failure occurred

   start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --user $DELUGED_USER --pidfile $PIDFILE2
   RETVAL2="$?"
   start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --user $DELUGED_USER --pidfile $PIDFILE1
   RETVAL1="$?"
   [ "$RETVAL1" = "2" -o "$RETVAL2" = "2" ] && return 2

   rm -f $PIDFILE1 $PIDFILE2

   [ "$RETVAL1" = "0" -a "$RETVAL2" = "0" ] && return 0 || return 1
}

case "$1" in
  start)
   [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME1"
   do_start
   case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
   esac
   ;;
  stop)
   [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME1"
   do_stop
   case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
   esac
   ;;
  restart|force-reload)
   log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME1"
   do_stop
   case "$?" in
     0|1)
      do_start
      case "$?" in
         0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
         1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
         *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
      esac
      ;;
     *)
        # Failed to stop
      log_end_msg 1
      ;;
   esac
   ;;
  *)
   echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
   exit 3
   ;;
esac

:
```

Comment: How-to quality is okay, explanation...not so much. Could you edit your answer to include a *little* more explanation please? Thanks.

Comment: I've explained the commands.  Explaining the entire script is a bit out of the scope of the question, imo, as it is complex and involves RTM.

Comment: The script pasted in this answer does not handle web-ui daemon launch as asked by the OP. [This script](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu) should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, deluge does not have init scripts in current debian, as well as in ubuntu and a bunch of other Linuxes. They have guides on creating such scripts though: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript (and [one especially for debian&ubuntu](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu)). It should not be that hard, but I switched to transmission because of this extra work.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an (old) outstanding issue:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=541138

You might try the version from Debian Expirimental, see:

http://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental and http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=experimental&searchon=names&keywords=deluged

Comment: You happen to have triggered one of my pet peeves - the notorious link answer. **Please do NOT give link answers** as they are bad for several reasons:  #1 They are subject to becoming invalid. #2 They are not helpful to the OP - Stack Exchange is a site *for* answers, not a way to find out *where to get them.*  **Please remember this for future reference.**

Comment: agree with @xxmbabanexx , if you are going to post a link, please explain the content of the link, this will provide help should the link become outdated.

Comment: It's very unlikely these links will be invalid before this question itself becomes invalid. Should I have answered  'yes, deluged doesn't have init scripts' instead? Or 'go check the relevant Debian packages an find the answer yourself'?